# Refactor: Eliminate two each in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, refactoring

I am trying to generate all poker cards (52 of cards), here is how I do it:

```
ranks = '23456789TJQKA'.split ''
suits = 'SHDC'.split ''
my_deck = []

ranks.each do |r|
  suits.each { |s| my_deck << r+s }
end

my_deck # => ["2S", "2H", "2D", "2C", "3S", "3H", "3D", "3C", "4S", "4H", "4D", "4C", "5S", "5H", "5D", "5C", "6S", "6H", "6D", "6C", "7S", "7H", "7D", "7C", "8S", "8H", "8D", "8C", "9S", "9H", "9D", "9C", "TS", "TH", "TD", "TC", "JS", "JH", "JD", "JC", "QS", "QH", "QD", "QC", "KS", "KH", "KD", "KC", "AS", "AH", "AD", "AC"]
```

My friends who use python shows me this:

```
[r+s for r in '23456789TJQKA' for s in 'SHDC']
```

Does anyone could give me advice on how to make the above code more beautiful as the Python version? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's fine as its written.

Comment: Thanks. Asking to see other possibilities.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to write this using [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
ranks = %w(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 T J Q K A)
suits = %w(S H D C)

my_deck = ranks.product(suits).map(&:join)
#=> ["2S", "2H", "2D", "2C", "3S", "3H", "3D", "3C", "4S", "4H", "4D", "4C", "5S", "5H", "5D", "5C", "6S", "6H", "6D", "6C", "7S", "7H", "7D", "7C", "8S", "8H", "8D", "8C", "9S", "9H", "9D", "9C", "TS", "TH", "TD", "TC", "JS", "JH", "JD", "JC", "QS", "QH", "QD", "QC", "KS", "KH", "KD", "KC", "AS", "AH", "AD", "AC"]
```

Comment: Thank you, the use of `product`, `map`, and `join` is beautiful.

Comment: There is no other option to make it more sweetest.. :) +1

Answer (score -1):

It’s a matter of opinion. You could use `%w()` instead of the `.split`, more descriptive variable names, string interpolation, and the more idiomatic `map` rather than the iterative programming-esque `each`s.

```
ranks = %w{2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 T J Q K A}
suits = %w{S H D C}

my_deck = ranks.map{|rank| suits.map{|suit| "#{rank}#{suit}" }}.flatten
```